# Can't relase the lock with notify

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, wait, notify

I've got a test on java thread coding but i have some basic problem.. after hours of trying and searching I decided to try there!

I can't understand why my wait is still locked even after my notify :

Here you can find my code:

```
public class Mymain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for( int i=0;i<100;i++){
            new ThreadClass(i).start();     
        }
    }
}

public class ThreadClass extends Thread {
    static boolean ok = false;
    int id;

    public ThreadClass(int i) {
        id = i;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread start " + id);
        Last.toDo(id);
        if (id == 5)
            try {
                waiting();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        if (id != 5)
            awaking();

        System.out.println("thread end " + id);
    }

    private synchronized void awaking() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (ok) {
            System.out.println("i'm " + id + " and i'm Awaking 5");
            ok = false;
            notify();
            System.out.println("I did the notify and i'm " + id);
        }
    }

    private synchronized void waiting() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Sleeping");
        ok = true;
        wait();
        System.out.println("Awake 5");
    }
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjx3u.png)

Then it starts looping or it goes in dead lock not sure.. it should just stop the thread with id=5 and then the next thread should re-start the id = 5.. but thread 5 never wake up after the notify...

In the result as you can see I got 2 threads trying to wake up the thread 5 and thread 5 is always waiting since the start^^

Comment: Can you show us what your output is, and what it should be?

Comment: Can you put that in your question so it can be formatted for easy analysis?

Comment: @WarrenDew Done^^

Comment: Just for the record, the answer you accepted is really not clear and does not make sense.  Please consider choosing another.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look I did a few changes to your code:

1. You can't just `notify()` , you'll notify to `this`. And you can't just `wait()` , you'll wait forever. You have to use these function over an Object, so i added an `Integer` object (just to show you - you'll have to choose the right object).
2. You have yo understand between `synchronized` and `static synchronized`. A quick search would lead you to a perfect answer.
3. Why function `waiting()` is synchronized? only thread number 5 calls it.
4. When calling to an `Object.notify()` / `Object.wait()`, you have to declare a synchronized block over the object.

Here's some code:

```
public class Threads {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer intObject = new Integer(0);
        for( int i=0;i<100;i++){

            new ThreadClass(i, intObject).start();     
        }
    }
}
class ThreadClass extends Thread {
    static boolean ok = false;
    int id;
    Integer intObject;
    public ThreadClass(int i, Integer intObject) {
        id = i;
        this.intObject = intObject;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread start " + id);
        //Last.toDo(id);
        if (id == 5)
            waiting();
        else
            awaking(this);

        System.out.println("thread end " + id);
    }

    private static synchronized void awaking(ThreadClass t) {
        if(ok) {
            System.out.println("i'm " + t.id + " and i'm Awaking 5");
            ok = false;
            synchronized (t.intObject) {
                    t.intObject.notify();
                }
            System.out.println("I did the notify and i'm " + t.id);
        }
    }
    private void waiting(){
        System.out.println("Sleeping");
        ok = true;
        synchronized (intObject) {
            try {
                intObject.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Awake 5");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i wrote it, just to demonstrate how to work with synchronized over an Object

Comment: This will not work.  Instead of locking on `this` you are locking on an an autoboxed `Integer` field which is worse.  First off no one else is going to call notify on it so you still have the same problem.  But also it is a terrible pattern (like @NathanHughes) to wait/notify on an object that can be easily changed.  Lock objects should also be `final` at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not calling notify() on the same object that you called wait() on.  In particular, thread 5 is calling wait() on itself, but thread 8, for example, is calling notify() on itself, not on thread 5.  As a result, thread 5 is never getting notified.

Also, you need to make the `ok` variable `volatile` to ensure that when one thread sets it, the other threads can see the change.  This isn't causing you a problem in this particular case, but it could cause a problem in other cases.

Comment: I came up to this end too  (first 3 line) but i'm not understanding how should i do to notify thread 5. That's probably something basic i'm ignoring..^^

Ty for the help :D

Comment: One way to do it would be to replace the "ok" variable with a volatile Object variable.  You'd check for nonnull instead of true, and thread 5 would create the object and wait on it.  The other threads would notify it if it were there.

Comment: Yeah i got it ty for all ^^

Answer (score 0):

> i can't understand why my wait is still locked even after my notify :

Wait and notify work when the same object *instance* is used.  If you for example have:

```
 String x1 = "...";
 String x2 = "...";
```

and thread #1 does:

```
synchronized (x1) { x1.wait(); }
```

and thread #2 then does:

```
synchronized (x2) { x2.wait(); }
```

Then thread #1 will still be waiting because the notify was only for `x2`.  In your example, the thread with id 5 is waiting on its own instance of `ThreadClass` since you are using method synchronization.  Then when other threads call `awaking()` they too are calling notify on their instances of `ThreadClass`.  If you want thread #5 to see the other thread's notify then they should share a lock object.

Maybe something like:

```
 final Object lock = new Object();
 for (int id = 0; id < 100; id++){
        new ThreadClass(id, lock).start();     
 }
 ...
 public class ThreadClass extends Thread {
     private final Object lock;
     ...
     public ThreadClass(int id, Object lock) {
         this.id = id;
         this.lock = lock;
     }
     ...
     private void awaking() {
        ...
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notify();
        }
        ...
     }
     private void waiting() throws InterruptedException {
        ...
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.wait();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use **notifyAll()** method? When you invoke notify(), it means that only one thread will change a status from **waiting** to **runnable**, but there can be the situations when you have more than one thread and other threads which are waiting in the line as well, they will not receive this notification. In my opinion it is preferable to use notifyAll.

Comment: Don't think so^^ i solved as suggested from the other members^^

Comment: This post doesn't answer the question accurately. If the threads don't use the same lock it doesn't matter which method they call.